# Dead code warning where it shouldn't be

Tags: java, eclipse, dead-code

I have a very simple Java code, like this (this is just an excerpt):

```
for(;;)
{
  AnObject object = null;
  for(AnObject elem : list) // where the list is of the type List<AnObject>
  {
    if(<some dynamic condition goes here>)
    {
      object = elem;
    }
  }

  Log.v(TAG, object.property); // was initially omitted, added for the answer

  // more code skipped for simplicity

  if(object == null)
  {                  //
    break;           //
  }                  // this all is marked as dead code
}
```

In Eclipse, the fragment with comments is marked as a dead code. Why? There is no `final` elements in the condition. The `object` variable is not assigned anywhere to constant null, except for the very beginning of the cycle, after which it should be normally overriden, but it does not happen always. The `object` can very well be null and non-null.

Am I missing something?

**The Answer**

Well, I found the answer, and to show it I must add one line of code to my example, which I omitted by accident when tried to simplify the code excerpt, but it is important. The line is:

```
Log.v(TAG, object.property);
```

So the object must be non-null, otherwise the code unreachable by exception. This line was added temporary for debugging purposes, which is why it was out of my consideration.

Comment: Post an SSCCE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, uhm, this will probably take a while to prepare.

Comment: What you show right now doesn't demonstrate the problem. I don't know how anyone could help you at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't do it for me.

Comment: What compiler? If you are indeed initializing the list to a non-null value (we're so far assuming that it is non-null because of your statements in the question), this shouldn't happen.

Comment: For `list == null` Eclipse would issue the warning `list can only be null at this point`.

Comment: Yeah, to get that warning, list is definitely initialized, but it must believe that there's no way you'll ever leave the `for` loop without also leaving the parent loop. I'm not sure how you'd achieve that, but whatever code is missing inside that `for` loop is likely the culprit.

Comment: @Thor84no, you are right, I added explanations into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that warning in eclipse.

Could it be that you accidently forgot some piece of code in your original question which might lead to a situation where no code behind it is executed. As you marked the complete `if` statement as dead code and not just its body, this seems to be the case. That missing line could be something that actually uses `object` (probably as simple as a logging statement where you try to access one of `object`'s properties).

Even if the `if` condition is not marked as dead, its body might still be. Either `object` is not `null` (and the `if` body would not be executed) or – if `object` is null – a `NullPointerException` would be thrown in that missing line so that the execution stops there.

Comment: I'm wonder, if compiler found out that object can not be null because otherwise the code will raise null pointer exception in the logging line above, why didn't it mark the logging line itself as dangerous?

Comment: A `NullPointerException` is [unchecked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html), so the only thing Eclipse complains about is the unreachable code. The line is not that dangerous if your code makes sure `object` isn't `null`, which is what the compiler "assumes".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, yet it's not clear why the line with `object.property` makes compiler assume that the object is not `null`.  Could you shed some light? I'm puzzled a bit.

Comment: Either your code blew up (`NPE` is unchecked, so noone complains about that possibility) or `object` != null.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce with the following program:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(;;)
        {
            List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
          Object object = null;
          for(Object elem : list) 
          {
            if(new Date().getSeconds() % 3 == 0)
            {
              object = elem;
            }
          }
          if(object == null) 
          {                  
            break;           
          }                  
        }

    }

}
```

This is Eclipse 3.7.2 with Java SE 1.7

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Because, if list is null (in your code there's no init for list), you won't ever initialize Object.</strike>
My Trashtalk, my bad.

If the inner 'if' always go false, the dead code could be marked inside it. 
If the elements are null, the comparisson in the end still applies.
If you return before your dead code block, it will raise an unreachable code error.

As others say, couldn't replicate it.

Comment: See the program below: With `List<Object> = null` it still doesn't show dead code in Eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: Hmmm, it's because eclipse raises warning BEFORE, in the foreach (Null pointer access warning on list in the foreach)

Comment: Yes, it does. It still doesn't show the behaviour described by the OP: dead code in the indicated section.